# Using std::ptr_fun for a member function

Tags: c++, c++03

Consider the following:

```
class A
{
    public:
    bool is_odd(int i)
    {
        return (i % 2) != 0;
    }

    void fun()
    {
        std::vector<int> v2;
        v2.push_back(4);
        v2.push_back(5);
        v2.push_back(6);

        // fails here
        v2.erase(std::remove_if(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::not1(std::ptr_fun(is_odd))), v2.end());
    }
};
```

The above code fails to negate the effect of `is_odd()` because it is a member function. The call to `std::ptr_fun()` fails.

How do I make it to work? Please note that I want `is_odd()` to be a non-static member function.

Comment: Make `is_odd` a static function? Or a non-member function? There's no reason it should be a member function.

Comment: @HappyCoder: Make it a static member function then.

Comment: You can write a functor class that's *like* the type of `[this](int n){return is_odd(n);}` yourself and use that.

Comment: @KerrekSB Note that `is_odd()` is already part of my class. If I create a functor class, and do `!is_odd()`, I need the object of `A`. If not, there's code duplication (`is_odd` is just an example, actual code is actually huge)

Comment: Use the functor to implement `A::is_odd`, thus avoiding code duplication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple issues with using `A::is_odd(int)` as a unary predicate, especially when it needs to be used with `std::not1()`:

1. A call to `A::is_odd(int)` takes two arguments: the implicit object ("`this`") and the visible `int` argument.
2. It isn't a function object defining `argument_type` and `result_type`.

Properly using this member function as a unary predicate requires two steps:

1. Adapting the member function pointer to be a suitable function object, e.g., using one of the `std::mem_*fun` functions.
2. Binding the first argument to a suitable object, with a non-C++11 compiler probably using `std::bind1st()`.

With a C++11 compiler things are a lot easier because `std::bind()` take care of both of these. Assuming it is used from a member of `A`:

```
... std::not1(std::bind(&A::is_odd, this, std::placeholders::_1)) ...
```

The same with a pre-C++11 compiler is somewhat harder. The use in `std::remove_if()` would look something like this:

```
v2.erase(
    std::remove_if(v2.begin(),
                   v2.end(),
                   std::not1(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&A::is_odd), this))),
    v2.end());
```

Comment: Nice use of `std::mem_fun` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: yes. I didn't notice that it is called from a member of `A`. I updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just make `is_odd` static, so it won't require an implicit `this` parameter:

```
static bool is_odd(int i)
```

It doesn't use any member variables or other member functions anyway.